# How to make this symbol?

Tags: symbols

How can I make this symbol?

[image]

Already searched through ["Latex Symbols"](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), but can't find it.

Comment: Try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html, "detexify"; it's quite good at finding symbols for you.

Comment: See Table 132 (p 50) of the the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: The line going from bottom left to top right in `\varkappa`, which is what detixify and Werner suggest, is close to 45 degrees whereas in this symbol this line is steeper. I think it's probably an `H` in some weird and wonderful font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\varkappa
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I didn't know that it is a kappa. I thought it is some kind of curvy H ;)

Comment: That's the way `ϰ ` is typeset when you study Ancient Greek…